# Does the Blender Game Engine Support Texture Nodes?

Tags: materials, game-engine, node-editor

I have a nice procedural dirt texture made up for a sphere, but when I play the game with an object that utilizes the texture, it will only show the color of the defuse and completely ignore any textures.

Even when I switch back to the Blender Render mode, the renders will not display the texture.
Hopefully this image will give you some context.

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure but it may be that nodes aren't supported in the BGE (could be a performance choice). You can use the nodes material you have to bake to an image texture that can be used within the BGE

Comment: BGE doesn't support generated textures. Try baking the textures to an image.

Comment: If you post that as an answer I could mark it as the answer. That way people who stumble upon this will see it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using GLSL shading mode, and the *Nodes* option is checked in the render tab of the properties window (by default it is); then the BGE supports material nodes. However procedural textures, and generated texture coordinates are not supported.
[image: shading options for the BGE]

---

To be able to use your procedural material, you will have to [bake it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13390/2217), then use the resulting image in a new material in the game.