# how to bake texture from multiple overlayed uv Islands to individual uv islands

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I wanted to ask, how you could quickly bake/transfer the texture from overlaying UV islands to individual UV islands?

the "Selected to Active" option in the baking menu was activated while baking the hair texture to the newly unwrapped mesh with a new assigned texture  but that gave out a white result.

[image: baking texture from multiple overlaying uv islands to seperate uv islands]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a second UV map on your object in *Properties > Object Data* and unwrap it so it has individual islands (or however you want)

   [image]

## Blender Internal

2. Add your existing texture to the object and select the appropriate UV map in *Properties > Textures > Mapping > Map*:

   [image]
3. Create a new image in the UV/Image editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> or *Header > Image > New*
4. Select the new UV map in *Properties > Object Data* and then select the new image in the image editor, so that the individual islands UV map is displayed over the new image.

   [image]
5. Press *Bake* in *Properties > Render > Bake*:

   [image]

## Cycles

To do the same in cycles, you can use attribute nodes:

1. Add two attribute nodes and enter the names of your UV maps. You can now use the *Vector* output of these as those UV coordinates.
2. Create a new image in the image editor and add it to the node setup with a texture node. Plug the mapping you want into that texture node and select it.

   [image]
3. With that texture node selected, press Bake in *Render settings > Bake*.

Comment: gandalf3: We also now have a dedicated UV map node which is available for newer builds.  It's in the 'Input' list.