# UV fit in picture while baking

Tags: uv

Firstly, I am a beginner in blender and my English is not good.

I have a single object with several materials and would like to bake all the materials in a single image. The problem is that the UV is larger than the output image, because each material has textures of different dimensions and when I do the bake, the output image is cut off.

Will I have to redo my UV, or is there anything I can do to make the output image fit?

[image]

Comment: Yes you need  to redo the UV map, but it's better to create new one for that and bake from materials which use 1 UV map to texture using another one. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13383/how-to-bake-texture-from-multiple-overlayed-uv-islands-to-individual-uv-islands (the only difference with new Blender versions is they have dedicated UV Map node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In object mode select the object with RMB and Ctrl A to apply (object/apply/scale)..then go to edit mode press u to unwrap..i have same issue before and this tips solve mine..i wish it helps you as well..

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the UV so that it fits the image. It gave more work, but it's better to start the job. Thanks for the answers.